# Python scraping: difference between manually attained page and page collected with request/bs4

Tags: python, html

I am trying trying to scrape the following [page](http://search.ft.com/search?q=&t=all&rpp=100&fa=people&s=-lastPublishDateTime&f=lastPublishDateTime%5B2017-08-01T00%3A00%3A00%2C2017-08-01T23%3A59%3A59%5D).

In my web browser i can see the following box at the bottom right of the results - according to the inspect panel it is an "ol" tag with class attribute "pagination".

[image]

However if i try to scrape the page with python:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url='http://search.ft.com/search?q=&t=all&rpp=100&fa=people&s=-lastPublishDateTime&f=lastPublishDateTime%5B2017-08-01T00%3A00%3A00%2C2017-08-01T23%3A59%3A59%5D'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('ol', {'class': 'pagination'})
```

`results` is an empty list.

To troubleshoot i visualized the downloaded page with `print(soup.prettify)` and compared it to the source code of the original page. To my surprise they are different! And the downloaded page doesn't contain the `<ol class="pagination">` tag that i am looking for.

Anyone has been confronted to that problem before / can offer some guidance and tips?

Comment: Evidently the page content is loaded using JavaScript, not just in the raw HTML

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok sorry i am quite new to scraping. I had that scraper done for me before with only requests and bs4 and i am trying to understand it to redo it it with aiohttp. But it is true in the original version it is not reaching for that `ol` tag.

Comment: when you're doing scraping, you might be interested in the "network" tab and extensions like "yesscript" to disable javascript on certain pages.